# How to serialise payment details in google protocol buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers, bitcoin

In particular I'm trying to successfully return a payment object to the `bitcoin` client,
this line of code:

```
required bytes serialized_payment_details = 4;
```

in the `PaymentRequest` message of `.proto` is required but I don't know how to generate the serialised payment details or even what it means to be honest?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

```
serialized_payment_details = PaymentDetailsObject.SerializeToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

**all** that does is declare that field 4 should hold a blob - a sequence of raw data. No meaning, translation or intent is provided for that, so *all* processing must be done externally to protocol buffers. As for how to serialize it: that comes down to bitcoin and whatever bitcoin library / tools you are using.

Comment: could you possibly describe a scenario or give an example in python code at all please?

Comment: @derrend frankly, I strongly suggest you split the two concepts: figure out how to serialize bitcoin data to a blob, and **separately** figure out how to embed a blob in protobuf. I know lots about protobuf, but not from python, and next-to-nothing about bitcoin.

Comment: I think I have it, there is a message container higher in the file with "message PaymentDetails { some fields }, so "serialized_payment_details = PaymentDetailsObject.SerializeToString()" is the answer. Does that sound correct?